# Custom header links inside table don't work

Tags: markdown

I've create table inside [GitHub Flavored Markdown](https://help.github.com/articles/github-flavored-markdown) document using HTML, but I wasn't able to make working links to paragraphs using custom IDs.

I have defined header with custom id `{#A1}`, and when I try to make a link to it inside table, `<td>[A1](#A1)</td>`, it just shows syntax.

Proposed solution for this was to make spaces between HTML tags and Markdown syntax, and to even have empy lines between them, but both solutions didn't work for me.

Comment: And the code sample producing problems is...? Hint: [mcve]